# websocket connection between services in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, websocket

I have two services in Kubernetes (k3s) one is backend and another is frontend and I need the transfer data from backend to fronted through websocket. When I debug in docker-compose it works. So when run in docker-compose on backend I have (python):

```
import websockets
...
start_server = websockets.serve(server, "0.0.0.0", 8001)
...
```

On front I have (html):

```
...
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001');
...
```

And I have function onclose:

```
        ws.onclose = function (e) {
            document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = 'Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 5 seconds...' + e.reason;
            setTimeout(function () {
                connect();
            }, 5000);
        };
```

And it's works as should.

When I use k3s I get `Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 5 seconds...`

There is my backend (app) deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
        name: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            - python3.9
            - main.py
          image: app
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          name: app
          ports:
            - name: app
              containerPort: 8001
```

And service manifest for backend:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: app-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 8001
      targetPort: app
  selector:
    app: app
```

My frontend deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
        name: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            - python3.9
            - -m
            - uvicorn
            - main:app
            - --reload
            - --port
            - "8000"
            - --host
            - 0.0.0.0
          image: frontend
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          name: frontend
          ports:
            - name: frontend
              containerPort: 8000
```

Service for frontend:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  type: ClusterIP 
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: frontend
  selector:
    app: frontend
```

I have Ingress Controller (traefic) that routes traffic to cluster:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-dns.ca
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: frontend-service
              port:
                number: 8000
```

I changed the code in html in this way:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://app-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8001');
```

but get ````Socket is closed. Reconnect will be attempted in 5 seconds... ```

How to get connection between services or debug connection?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Were you able to solve this?